Is there a working way to compile node JS code to single executable?
I've been struggling to find a working method. All the solutions I see are at least 4 yrs old, advice modules that are depeciated like PKG or Nexe or crashing. Node 23 native solution only Handles CommonJs. I'm using Express, ES6 and EJS. Please Help!
I've tried:
PKG and solutions wrapping it
Nexe
Caxa
Nw
Native node 23 compiler
...
About 2 dozens of other npm packages

I would suggest use [PKG] (https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg) , but could mention it was not working.
